# Изменение компонента в joomla

Tags: joomla

Нужно внести изменения в вёрстку, а именно в файл
`components/com_adsmanager/views/details/tmpl/default.php`
Можно ли в joomla изменять эти файлы компонента?
Или подскажите пожалуйста, как это нужно делать правильно?

Правильно ли я понял, что это нужно делать через менеджер шаблонов - создать переопределение?

Answer (score 0):

да, конечно, вы можете переопределить любой layout представления компонента в своем шаблоне, скопируйте этот файл в папку templates/ваш_шаблон/html/com_adsmanager/details/

все layouts можно переопределять, будь то системные, будь то представления компонента или модуля, все они должны быть в папочке html вашего шаблона

в данном случае вы создаете папочку com_adsmanager в папочке html;
в папочке com_adsmanager создаете папочку с названием представления, в нашем случае details;
ну и в последней создаете файл layoutа который вы хотите переопределить, это default.php